# Generic picking solution for 3D scenes with vertex-shader-based geometry deformation applied

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader, openscenegraph, picking

I'm trying to implement a navigation technique for 3D scenes (in OpenSceneGraph with OpenGL). Among other things the user should be able to click on an scene object on the screen to move towards it.

The navigation technique should be integrated into another project which uses a vertex shader to apply a global deformation to the scene geometry. And here is the problem: Since the geometry is deformed using a vertex shader, it is not straight forward to un-project the mouse cursor position to the world coordinates of the spot the user actually selected. But I need those coordinates to perform the proper camera movement in my navigation technique.

One way of performing this un-projection would be to modify the vertex shader (used for the deformation) to let it also store the vertex' original position and normal in separate textures. Afterwards one could read those textures at the mouse position to get the desired values.

Now, as I said, the vertex shader belongs to another project which I actually don't want to touch. One goal of my navigation technique is to be as generic as possible to be easily integrated into other projects as well.

So here is the question: Is there any feature in OpenSceneGraph or OpenGL that I did not consider so far? Anything that allows me to get the world coordinates of a fragment, independently of the vertex shader coder?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always do an OpenGL selection operation:
http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html

Alternately, you could rasterize to a very small (1px*1px) framebuffer where the user clicked, read back the z-buffer and unproject the Z value you got into world space.

Comment: What you describe is the "normal" approach for picking in 3D scenes. My problem is that the geometry is deformed in the vertex shader, which means the position of geometry you see on the screen is not its actual position in world coordinates.